# How do i make sure the array is filled in Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const userfetched =[];
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response=> response.json()).then(user=>userfetched.push(user));
console.log(userfetched)
```

here it outputs empty array.

but if i use the following code :

```
const userfetched =[];
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response=> response.json()).then(user=>console.log(user));
console.log('end')
```

it outputs 
end
then the array values.

How do i wait till the fetch response is filled and iterate over it?

Comment: code execution outside of then continues , inside then executes when the promise returns(async). thats why you having this issue

Comment: How do I fix this , sorry I am new to js.. and not sure how to fix . Just trying to learn

Comment: well if you want to be in sync with promise you have to console.log inside second then . this is where promise is resolved

Comment: The answers posted works , but not able to export . I used state variable to bind the data to render . Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

Just put `console.log(userfetched)` after fetch promise resolves and parsed to json:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(user => { 
      console.log(user) 
      // and do whatever you wanna do here
  });
```

Comment: That's because it has not got the response yet. After fetch promise is resolved (server responded) and it parsed to json the `console.log` can execute.

Comment: Ah I need to export after pushing those values

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Call callApi function once the featch is complete and push the responce to the array and console the result

its working async change to sync

```
const userfetched = [];
class App extends Component {

     async callApi() {
       var res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
       var result = await res.json()
       console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
     }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.callApi()
      }

   render{
        return( //do something.... )
   }
}
```

Comment: had compile errors, corrected and run .. not working still . got empty array

Comment: are you using any function to call the fetch ?

Comment: no whatever i gave in the question is the actual code, i am using

Comment: you can write a fetch inside a function and call that a function name where ever you want this.callApi()

Comment: and using async await for that function

Comment: same issue again :(

Comment: tried this : const getdata = async () =>
{
  const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  const result = await data.json();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
};
getdata();
console.log('end');

Comment: where did you call the getdata function inside a class or outside a class ?

Comment: There is no class . It’s just a file with one function you recommended and I invoked in that file

Comment: you can put the code to your browser console const getdata1 = async () => { const data = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"); const result = await data.json(); console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); }; getdata1()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171535/discussion-between-saravanakumar-v-and-prabhu).

Comment: it works when printing . But not able to export it .. I changed the code to utilize state variable , so for now it is working